# UML : all use cases require login

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, use-case

I am working on a language learning platform and i made the following use case diagram :

[image]

My question is : if all my use-cases require the user to be logged in, is the way i used considered correct, or there is a better approach

Comment: I'm afraid you are not doing use case analyses, but rather functional decomposition. Hardly any of your "use cases" are actually use cases. Most are functions or something at that level.

Comment: it does, but i would prefer to include the login use-case in the diagram because my internship supervisor wants me to

Comment: Your supervisor is wrong then. Like so many teaching UML and not getting the point of use cases. He should start learning instead. Recommend him Bittner/Spence about UC - best read one can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Geert and qwerty_so, (two of our best UML master), your use case diagram looks like a list of possible actions/functionality than use case for me.You should focus on the sytem **main usages**.
According to your diagram *login* seems to be the central/first point, it should be more *browsing activities* or *something else* even if your student must login to do something else.
So try to identify your **main** **usecases** then they would include or be extended by other secondary usecases.
I gave you an example try to understand what I meant by that.
[image]

Comment: There's a lot fuzz around the login. It's no UC but a simple constraint. Login does not add any value which a UC is meant to show. You won't get paid for Login, will you? (I refrain from UV for this bubble being still shown. Else your answer is correct.)

Comment: Agreed !! I added it because it is mandatory and none relevant...

Comment: Really a pity that teaching UML is so broken (as can be seen in many posts here). I will probably not see it fixed in my life time, but hope dies last ;-)